# is there a lag function that redefines itself on each line of the data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, iteration, lag

In my dataframe I want to define a column based on previous values of another column which changes in dynamic.
I know the tidyverse package has the lag function that return the value of the prevous row from the designated column. But the lag function doesn't take in count the changes on the designated columns during de dynamic.

The example below is just an oversimplification of the problem just for better understanding. It reproduces a cyclic iteration.

```
library(tidyverse)

H = 10
initial_a = 10
initial_b = 0

df = tibble(period = 0:H) %>%
  mutate(
    a = initial_a,
    
    b = ifelse(is.na(lag(a)), initial_b, lag(a)),
    
    a = period * initial_a
  )

view(df)
```

I want to obtain the below result :

```
 period     a     b
    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1      0     0     0
 2      1    10     0
 3      2    20    10
 4      3    30    20
 5      4    40    30
 6      5    50    40
 7      6    60    50
 8      7    70    60
 9      8    80    70
10      9    90    80
11     10   100    90
```

But all I obtain is this :

```
 period     a     b
    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1      0     0     0
 2      1    10    10
 3      2    20    10
 4      3    30    10
 5      4    40    10
 6      5    50    10
 7      6    60    10
 8      7    70    10
 9      8    80    10
10      9    90    10
11     10   100    10
```

I know where is the problem : the lag function isn't updateted at each line. It's calculated with the initial value of 'a' column.

So my question is : is there a function that allows to update the values of column 'a' at each step and take the value on the previous row.

Comment: What is `H` in the code

Comment: I'm getting `Error in eval_tidy(xs[[j]], mask) : object 'H' not found` when trying to reproduce your dataset

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to loop through anything. Define `a` and then use `lag(col, default = val)` to create `b`.

```r
library(dplyr)

initial_a = 10
initial_b = 0
H = 10

tibble(period = 0:H) %>% 
  mutate(a = period * initial_a, 
         b = lag(a, default = initial_b))
#> # A tibble: 11 x 3
#>    period     a     b
#>     <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1      0     0     0
#>  2      1    10     0
#>  3      2    20    10
#>  4      3    30    20
#>  5      4    40    30
#>  6      5    50    40
#>  7      6    60    50
#>  8      7    70    60
#>  9      8    80    70
#> 10      9    90    80
#> 11     10   100    90
```

Answer (score 2):

The example shown is a simple arithmetic series which does not require iteration but assuming that the real problem is more complicated and does then `Reduce` gives a way to use the prior value after it has been calculated.  `Reduce`  will pass the value calculated in the previous iteration as x and the current value of `period` in y (which in this problem is not used).

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))

initial_a = 10
initial_b = 0
data.frame(period = 0:10) %>%
  mutate(a = Reduce(function(x, y) x + initial_a, period,  acc = TRUE),
         b = dplyr::lag(a, default = initial_b))
```

giving:

```
   period   a  b
1       0   0  0
2       1  10  0
3       2  20 10
4       3  30 20
5       4  40 30
6       5  50 40
7       6  60 50
8       7  70 60
9       8  80 70
10      9  90 80
11     10 100 90
```